# How to register component directly vuetify-date-range picker ? Cannot get custom element

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I intall https://github.com/praveenpuglia/vuetify-daterange-picker in my currently vue app with vuetify i follow the docs. but it get me an error.

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

//in main.js

[image]

//and in my component 
[image]

//package.json
[image]

//error
[image]

Comment: Show your code. Without them we can't help you

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev i edited my question. pls check above  thank you for your response.

Comment: Show how to you use DateRange in component's `<template>` section. Paste your code, not screenshots.

Comment: <v-daterange v-model="range"></v-daterange>

Comment: I think I get it. You must use name `<v-date-range>` or `<VDateRange>`

Comment: Shettt! hahaha  now its working you right man thanks a lot. i din't expect that error. because i just copy that in docs.

Comment: It would by nice if you check my answer below as a correct :)

Answer (score 1):

From link you provided:

```
// If you want to register this as a global component then
// in main.js
import VDateRange from 'vuetify-daterange-picker';
import 'vuetify-daterange-picker/dist/vuetify-daterange-picker.css';

Vue.use(VDateRange);
```

And in your components you can use VDateRange with name `v-date-range`:

```
<template> 
  <div>  
    <v-date-range :options="dateRangeOptions" @input="onDateRangeChange"></v-date-range>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: i also do that and follow this docs https://vuetify-daterange-picker.gitbook.io/docs/installation-and-usage. installation but still i get that error. all my package are latest.